# Show that $∫_U u^2 dx ≤C∫_U|Du|^2 dx$ where $C$ is a constant.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral

Fix $μ>0$ and let $U$ be an open, bounded, connected set, $U⊂R^n$. We use the usual notation of $S$ to denote the Lebesgue measure of a set $S⊂R^n$. If $|\left\{x∈U | u(x)=0\right\}|≥μ>0$ and $u∈H_0^1 (U)$, then show there exists a constant $C$, which depends on $n$, $μ$, and $U$, such that

$$∫_U u^2 dx ≤C∫_U|Du|^2  dx$$

So after doing some digging on Poincare's inequality I am still not sure how I would provide a proof for this.

Comment: This is the [Poincaré inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality). You probably have many questions on this forum around this topic.

Comment: @cs89 I cannot believe I did not recognize this, thanks for pointing that out and apologies for the lapse in memory.

Comment: I guess you meant to write $H^1(U)$ instead of $H^1_0(U)$, since otherwise you can use the standard Poincaré inequality. Now, to prove it for $u\in H^1(U)$, you can use an almost identical argument to the proof of the Poincaré inequality as in Theorem 5.8.1 of Evans, using the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem.